# How can the header's background of AMP's accordion be changed?

Tags: amp-html

A dark theme is used for a web page.  The default color theme of AMP's accordion does not look good:
[image]

```
<amp-accordion>
        <section>
            <h4>How can I change the header's background?</h4>
            <div>
                Test
            </div>
        </section>
        <section>
            <h4>Anybody?</h4>
            <div>
                Test
            </div>
        </section>
</amp-accordion>
```

The following in  does not have any effect:

```
h4 {
    background-color: #333
}
```

Could anyone help?
Please note that AMP does not allow !important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining a class on the `h4` and applying the background colour to that. I just got it to work in the AMP By Example playground and it didn't complain about it and changed the background colour.

```css
h4.test {background-color: #ff0;}
```

```html
  <amp-accordion>
    <section expanded>
      <h4 class="test">Section 1</h4>
      <p>Bunch of awesome content.</p>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h4 class="test">Section 2</h4>
      <div>Bunch of even more awesome content. This time in a <code>&lt;div&gt;</code>.</div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h4 class="test">Section 3</h4>
      <figure>
        <amp-img src="/img/amp.jpg" width="1080" height="610" layout="responsive" alt="an image"></amp-img>
        <figcaption>Images work as well.</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </section>
  </amp-accordion>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  You have become my de facto AMP adviser :). Hope your answers will help many others with the increasing popularity of AMP.

Comment: No problem! I personally just started using AMP this past January when my co-worker and I decided to make use of AMP as a framework for the website of the company we work for. Did a lot of learning and am still learning through helping people out here.